# Interesting parallelogram question

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> A parallelogram $ABCD$ is given with an acute angle at vertex $A$. The perpendicular bisector of $AB$ meets line segment $CD$ at point $x$. Diagonals of this parallelogram intersect at point $E$. Prove that $XE = \frac {1} {2}AD$.

I have no ideas to solve. What to do?
[image]

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. In particular, don't just say "I have no idea". The standard place to start is to look at your notes or book to see if there are related questions with worked solutions. Did you do this? (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F$ and $G$ be the midpoints of $AB$ and $CD$ respectively.

Since $\measuredangle FXG=90°$ and $E$ is the midpoint of $FG$ we conclude that $FE=XE=GE \implies XE = \frac {1} {2}AD$.

Comment: But how did you get FE=XE?

Comment: @Richardfeynman Because $E$ is the circumcenter of $\bigtriangleup FXG$.